# Why my 2 instances of Livecharts cartesian not working?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, livecharts

i am currently having a problem with my code.

Basically i need to show 2 graph in one grid of my application but it seems to be not working.
The problem is one graph will show and the 2nd one will not plot the graph.

Below is the code that is used:

XAML:

```
                   <Grid>
                        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="cartchartdb" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" Margin="10,249,578.4,218.2" >
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Average Gap (Meter)" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Time" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                        </lvc:CartesianChart>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid>
                        <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection2}" LegendLocation="Right" Margin="792,160,9.8,238" >
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Sales" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter2}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                                <lvc:Axis Title="Month" Labels="{Binding Labels2}"></lvc:Axis>
                            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                        </lvc:CartesianChart>
                    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
public MainWindow(){
cartchartinit();
cartchartinit2();
}

private void cartchartinit2()
    {
        SeriesCollection2 = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,7 }
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 2",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 6, 7, 3, 4 ,6 }
            }
        };

        Labels2 = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" };
        YFormatter2 = value => value.ToString("C");

        //modifying the series collection will animate and update the chart
        SeriesCollection2.Add(new LineSeries
        {
            Values = new ChartValues<double> { 5, 3, 2, 4 },
            LineSmoothness = 0 //straight lines, 1 really smooth lines
        });

        //modifying any series values will also animate and update the chart
        SeriesCollection2[2].Values.Add(5d);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection2 { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels2 { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> YFormatter2 { get; set; }

private void cartchartinit()
    {

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Average Vehicles Gap",
                Values = null
            },
           /* new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Avg Gap (Metre)",
                Values = null



            },*/

            /*new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 3",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4,2,7,2,7 },
                PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Square,
                PointGeometrySize = 15
            }*/
        };

        Labels = null;
        YFormatter = value => value.ToString("");

        

        DataContext = this;

    }
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }
```

When i just use the cartchartinit() method only, it works. but when i add the cartchartinit2(), it only plot the graph for the later chart. Am i doing this wrong?

A help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You may have noticed yourself, but adding number suffixes to the names of otherwise identical properties of your MainWindow class is a bad approach. What if your would have to show 10 charts? You should create a separate class with those three properties, e.g. call it ChartViewModel. Then you would create multiple instances of this class and assign them to the DataContext of multiple CartesianChart controls.

Comment: This would best (and nearly automatically) be done by putting the CartesianChart control in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl, which has its ItemsSource property bound to a collection of your ChartViewModel class. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: @Clemens After fiddling around and testing out your advice, i found out that the problem was the datacontext = this was set more than once in the code which probably causing both charts not initializing at the same time. nonetheless, thanks for the explanation on the data templating way, that is new for me and it actually make my code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first chart is empty, because the binding source is too.
You commented the initialization of the `SeriesCollection` property and set the `LineSeries.Values` property of the only series item to `null` ==> no data set to show here. You also have issues with property changes not being reported to the binding engine.

There are several issues with your code. To address the most important:

### Layout

Don't wrap each control into a `Grid`.
This adds nothing but render performance costs. The wrapper grids are absolutely redundant. `Grid` is a layout `Panel`, but currently you are not using it for element arrangement.

Don't use `Margin` to position your grids.
This doesn't allow your application to scale and a layout based on margins is cumbersome to implement.
If you need absolute positioning use `Canvas`. If you need relative positioning use a `Panel` like `Grid` e.g. for column and row based layout or a `StackPanel` for simple vertically or horizontally arranged elements.

Use `Margin` only for small adjustments, preferably to their relative screen position.

From your margins it looks like you want your charts displayed in two rows and two columns (diagonal from top left to bottom right). In this case use the `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                      Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" 
                      LegendLocation="Right">
    ...
  </lvc:CartesianChart>

  <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                      Series="{Binding SeriesCollection2}" 
                      LegendLocation="Right">
    ...
  </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

If you want to align the charts next to each other simply use a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">    
  <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" 
                      LegendLocation="Right">
    ...
  </lvc:CartesianChart>

  <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection2}" 
                      LegendLocation="Right">
    ...
  </lvc:CartesianChart>
</StackPanel>
```

### Data binding

You use data binding to assign the chart data to the chart. That's is fine.
But you are setting up the binding source *after* the XAML binding expressions are initialized. Since all your source properties e.g., `SeriesCollection` and `SeriesCollection2` are neither a `DependencyProperty` nor raising the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event, changes/assignments of those properties are not picked up by the binding engine. In your case it works, but only because you are refreshing the `Binding.Source`, by re-assigning `this.DataContext = this` after each property change.
This will force every binding in your view to initialize again.

In more complex applications this will noticeably increase startup time or lead to sluggish UI.
WPF by default inherits the `DataContext` property value down the visual tree (with exceptions e.g. `DataTemplate`): every child element shares implicitly the same `DataContext` of their parent.
This means refreshing this property affects the complete visual tree! ==> don't refresh the `Binding.Source` (especially the `DataContext`) just because the `Binding.Path` was updated.

Let the binding engine handle those changes:

Whenever the source property of a binding is expected to change dynamically, the source object must implement those properties as `DependencyProperty` or in case this object is not a `DependencyObject`, must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

See [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)

`Window` is a `DependencyObject`, therefore `MainWindow` should implement all properties that serve as binding source or binding target as `DependencyProerty`:

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SeriesCollection",
    typeof(SeriesCollection),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(SeriesCollection)));

  public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection
  {
    get => (SeriesCollection) GetValue(MainWindow.SeriesCollectionProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.SeriesCollectionProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesCollection2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SeriesCollection2",
    typeof(SeriesCollection),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(SeriesCollection)));

  public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection2
  {
    get => (SeriesCollection) GetValue(MainWindow.SeriesCollection2Property);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.SeriesCollection2Property, value);
  }

  ... // Do this for all properties that serve as binding source or target

  public MainwWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
  }

  private void cartchartinit()
  {
    // Aside from their slightly clumsy definition, 
    // dependency properties are used like common CLR properties
    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh sorry. i forgot to include the array input i used for the cartchartinit() values were initialized in the other functions. thanks for the explanation and correcting datacontext = this actually solved the problems. for the data binding and etc i think i will apply it from now on. thanks a lot